# How to send array to a get request in Angular 8 app?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to send list of ids to the server in a get request, I'm doing
the following:

```
public loadTripsByIds(tripsIds:number[]): Observable<any> {              
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('tripsIds', tripsIds.join(', '));    
    return this.http.get<TripObj[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/ByIds/Get`, {params: params});                        
  }
```

In the server api code ( rest) I have defined list:

```
@GET
@Path("Trips/ById/Get") 
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Trips> loadTripsById(@QueryParam("tripsIds") final List<String> tripsIds) {
```

What I actually getting in the server is a list with 1 item (String type) with
comma separated. for example "10001, 10002".
I can parse the string in the server side easily but looking for the right
way to send list to server where each element will be id.

Thanks.

Comment: This is purely a back-end question. Please update your question to explain what the back-end is, what Java framework you are using and update the tags for that. You'll get better help than just tagging as Angular. Thanks,

Comment: In the backed I have the correct code O think cause i expected list, the problem is the angualr doesn't send the list correctly

Comment: So: what the `loadTripsByIds` input arguments are, what does the outgoing request look like, and what is it supposed to look like?

Comment: fundsIds.join(', ') create a string which I probably need to change but not sure what to

Comment: Should work as expected if you just append the array as-is. Parameter serialization should take care of it: `params.append('tripsIds', tripsIds)`

Comment: params.append expect a string and not an array

Comment: You may need to change `tripsIds` to `tripsIds[]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to solve the problem I;m sending now array of param as follow:

```
let params = new HttpParams();
    for (let id of tripsIds) {
      params = params.append('tripIds', id); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a Java/Sprint developer, but some *back-end* frameworks handle *duplicate* query parameters as a collection. So you need a URL that looks like this.

```
http://example.com/?id=1&id=2
```

So try this, but I do not know if this helps.

```js
const params = tripIds.reduce((acc, next) => acc.append('tripsIds', next), new HttpParams());
```